# Scooby-Doo and The Loch Ness Monster's runtime difference?

Tags: scooby-doo

Is there missing footage on the blu-ray of Scooby-Doo and The Loch Ness Monster? 
The DVD states the film's runtime is 74 minutes. The blu-ray lists the runtime at 59 minutes, which is quite a significant difference.

Comment: I'm seeing Wikipedia also states the running time is 74 min. So, something fishy with the blu-ray.

Comment: Must be. I have the DVD, Scooby fan myself, and I purchased the blu-ray for my nephew as a Christmas gift. I noticed the runtime difference on the back right away. Strange. :/

Comment: I believe this must be a factory error. I own the blu-ray myself, and it states it's 59 minutes. I just let the entire film play through. I started it at 2:57, the end credits finished rolling at 4:11. That's 74 minutes, which is the runtime printed on the DVD.